# Where on the launchpad page given in the description is the ppa of openoffice that I need to add to get the repository?

Tags: launchpad, openoffice.org

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/amd64/openoffice.org/1:3.3.0-7ubuntu7

Please help me I've spent hours trying to figure out how to install openoffice on Quantal Ubuntu 12.10 and it is driving me nuts!

Comment: There aren't any PPAs on the page you've linked to. Quantal already has Lbre Office installed, is that not good enough?  I am not sure OpenOffice has been packaged for Quantal yet. You may want to watch [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~upubuntu-com/+archive/office) for updates.

Comment: Do you have any specific reason for using OpenOffice instead of LibreOffice which is included by default in Quantal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no longer an app called OpenOffice.org. It was renamed to LibreOffice, and it is installed by default on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Libre Office is a fork of Open Office and not a renamed application. AFAIK, Open Office still exists and can be installed on Ubuntu and other distros, though its development has been rather slow in the past couple of years.